# Getting generated xml from server control

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, servercontrol

I don't have much experience in server controls and xslt. I think I'm missing something fundamental and it seems that I can't find the right keywords to find what I need...

This works fine, it was not written by me. I'm just trying to understand it:

```
<CMS:FlexMenu ID="flexmenu1" runat="server" CssClass="usersClass" DefaultMenuID="83"
        WrapTag="div" AutoCollapseBranches="True" StartCollapsed="True" EnableMouseOverPopUp="False"
        EnableSmartOpen="True" StartLevel="1" MenuDepth="0" EnableAjax="False" DisplayXslt="/xmlfiles/flexmenu-to-list.xsl" />
```

This is an Ektron server control. If I needed to change or write a new xslt file, where can I find the structure of the XML?

I'm aware that you can write up an xslt that will spit out the raw xml. But my intuition tells me there has to be an easier way. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the FlexMenu control to write out the raw XML.

```
flexmenu1.DataBind();
Response.Write(flexmenu1.Text);
Response.End();
```